# Are outdoor equipment stores open on a Sunday afternoon in Arusha?

Tags: africa, tanzania, kilimanjaro

I'll arrive in Arusha on a Sunday around noon, to start a Kilimanjaro trek the day after. While I have most of the required/recommended gear, I need to get a few extra things. I have the option to rent from the trekking company, but I've also considered buying some of it as I might have use of it later. I haven't found good outdoor equipment stores in the country where I'm currently living, otherwise I'd have bought it already.

So, my question is twofold: are there stores for outdoor equipment in Arusha? If so, are they open on a Sunday afternoon?

Comment: In answering your question, I've not addressed the 'decent' part, as that is asking for opinions, which we don't do here on TSE. Otherwise, I hope the info helps. On your return, you can always add your own Answer with feedback on your experience there. As you know, it's helps develop content.

Comment: @Dorothy thanks for the reminder, I've edited the question to make it less opinion-based. I'd be happy to provide an answer after going there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kilimanjaro Review](http://www.kilimanjaro-review.com/arusha-city-guide/shops/clothing) offers a number of suggestions on where to pick up gear, and several have Sunday hours:

[Ezzy Spot Gents' Quality Garments](http://www.kilimanjaro-review.com/clothing/9-ezzy-spot-gents-quality-garments)
[AS Osman Outfitters](http://www.kilimanjaro-review.com/clothing/3-as-osman-outfitters)

The biggest and best shopping mall is the TFA Centre, often referred to as the Shoprite Centre, where several safari outfitters are located. It is open Mon - Sat 0900 - 1900, Sun 0900 – 1600.

Gear rental is also an option, and some make arrangements in advance of your arrival:

[Ascend Tanzania](http://www.ascendtanzania.com/gear-rental/)
[Base Camp Tanazania](http://basecamptanzania.com/climbing-equipments/)
[Climbing Kilimanjaro](http://www.climbingkilimanjaro.com/kilimanjaro-gear-rental)
[African Environments](http://www.africanenvironments.com/pages/climb/eqrent.htm)

Comment: This looks great - I'll mark it as accepted after I've been there.